# Rewrite double or if possible

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm currently doing some postgresql and i'm wondering if I can type this one in a more elegant way:

```
SELECT FOO.x AS A, FOO.y AS B, FOO.z AS C
FROM FOO
WHERE 
(FOO.x = 'car' and FOO.y = 'car' and FOO.z = 'boat')
OR
(FOO.x = 'car' and FOO.y = 'boat' and FOO.z = 'car')
OR
(FOO.x = 'boat' and FOO.y = 'car' and FOO.z = 'car')
```

As you can See I want that every row in the output contains two cars and exactly one boat. I can achieve that by the double OR inside the where, but I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this.

thanks in advance

EDIT: Sorry made a copy paste mistake, I've edited the where clause

Comment: There is certainly an error in your query, because you query is synonyme of: `SELECT FOO.x AS A, FOO.y AS B, FOO.z AS C
FROM FOO 
WHERE 
FOO.x = 'car' and FOO.y = 'boat'`

Comment: `SELECT FOO.x AS A, FOO.y AS B, FOO.z AS C
FROM FOO
WHERE 1=0;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use column concatenation. It's hard to talk about cleanness here. It's probably slower.

```
SELECT FOO.x AS A, FOO.y AS B, FOO.z AS C
FROM FOO
WHERE 
(FOO.x || FOO.y || FOO.z = 'carcarboat')
OR
(FOO.x || FOO.y || FOO.z = 'carboatcar')
OR
(FOO.x || FOO.y || FOO.z = 'boatcarcar')
```

Comment: IMHO it isn't cleaner in any way and also it will be slower to execute for sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
 (FOO.x = 'car') + (FOO.y = 'car') + (FOO.z = 'car') = 2
 AND 
 (FOO.x = 'boat') + (FOO.y = 'boat') + (FOO.z = 'boat') = 1
```

Possibly make use of an index (not sure what postgres does with a reversed IN clause & indexes):

```
 AND 'car' IN (x,y,z) 
 AND 'boat' IN (x,y,z)
```

Comment: The first example you gave doesn't work. :( 'ERROR: operator does not exist: boolean + boolean', haven't tried the second one

Comment: Ah, works in MySQL, I would have assumed it did in postgres... the second part is only an addendum to the first part, so nut useful on its own.

Comment: Yep, but not for postgres apparently :( (you could expand it with elaborate `CASE` statements, but it doesn't become more readable). I'll delete it in a moment.